# how to access all the properties of excel in asp.net like sheet name name, font, colour, bold, italic etc

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, excel

hey i have done coding to upload and display the excel file in asp.net
but the problem is :

1) How to know the sheet name of the excel file (i am taking sheet1 as default sheet but if user is trying to upload excel file having different sheet name then it is showing error

2)how to know the properties of the excel file like the headers of the excel file in which colour the data is having what size and font? So that my output that i am displaying will look the same as in excel file

Below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ExcelToAsp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((TxtFilePath.HasFile))
            {

                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                string query = null;
                string connString = "";
                string strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
                string strFileType =
                System.IO.Path.GetExtension(TxtFilePath.FileName).ToString().ToLower();
                //Check file type
                if (strFileType == ".xls" || strFileType == ".xlsx")
                    TxtFilePath.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedExcel/" + strFileName + strFileType));
                else
                {
                    LblMsg.Text = "Only excel files allowed";
                    LblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    LblMsg.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                string strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedExcel/" + strFileName + strFileType);

                //Connection String to Excel Workbook
                if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
                {
                    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                       strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
                {
                    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }

                query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";//query = "SELECT [Country],[Capital] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE[Currency]=’Rupee’"//query = "SELECT [Country],[Capital] FROM [Sheet1$]"

                //Create the connection object
                conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                //Open connection
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
                //Create the command object
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                GrvExcelData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                GrvExcelData.DataBind();
                LblMsg.Text = "Data retrieved successfully! Total Records:" + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                LblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                LblMsg.Visible = true;
                da.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                LblMsg.Text = "Please select an excel file first";
                LblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                LblMsg.Visible = true;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the connection's GetSchema() method to find the sheet names. For headers you'd look at the properties of the dataset fields. However, you won't get any formatting information using the OleDb approach - you'd need a different library (one suitable for server-side use).

Comment: I think you may need to use excel object for doing that. Please refer the links below [http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1370-reading-opening-excel-file-in-csharp-using-microsoftofficeintropexcel-objec.aspx](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1370-reading-opening-excel-file-in-csharp-using-microsoftofficeintropexcel-objec.aspx) [http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1370-reading-opening-excel-file-in-csharp-using-microsoftofficeintropexcel-objec.aspx](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1370-reading-opening-excel-file-in-csharp-using-microsoftofficeintropexcel-obje

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sheet names using oledb.

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
dtTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

Comment: This is my first post here in SOF and u guys are there to help... thanx for help... i will defintly try out ur answer...